# LED still on when transistor is closed with Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, npn

When simulating the following circuit, there is no problem. However, when I do it in real life, with a BC558 transistor, the LED stays on even when the Arduino is not sending any voltage.

The resistor going to the base is 20 kΩ and the one connecting to the LED is 1 kΩ. The power supply is sending a constant 12 V to the circuit.

When using a multimeter (irl), I notice that the power supply's voltage seem to be going through the Arduino causing it to seem like it is sending a voltage to the transistor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAYzFd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you describe how "the power supply's voltage seems to be going through the Arduino"?  Show us the code you are using as well, please.

Comment: Are you sure it worked in simulation? What is the supply voltage you connected to the LED +ve terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *when I do it in real life, with a BC558 transistor, the LED stays on
> even*

The BC558 is a PNP transistor and, I expect you should have used an NPN transistor like the BC548.

[image]

[image]

Images from [here](https://www.componentsinfo.com/).

> *When using a multimeter (irl), I notice that the power supply's
> voltage seem to be going through the Arduino causing it to seem like
> it is sending a voltage to the transistor.*

Yes that will happen because the collector base region is incorrectly forward biased with a PNP transistor.

Comment: Just tried with the BC548 and it worked. All this time I thought the BC558 was a NPN transistor.